# Context-free grammar describing regular expressions?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, syntax, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to write a regular expression engine. I'd like to write a recursive descent parser by hand. What would a context-free grammar without left recursion for the language of regular expressions (not the languages that can be described by regular expressions) look like? Would it be easiest to re-factor out the syntactic sugar, i.e. change `a+` to `aa*` ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Left recursion:

```
Expression = Expression '|' Sequence
           | Sequence
           ;

Sequence = Sequence Repetition
         | <empty>
         ;
```

Right recursion:

```
Expression = Sequence '|' Expression
           | Sequence
           ;

Sequence = Repetition Sequence
         | <empty>
         ;
```

Ambiguous form:

```
Expression = Expression '|' Expression
           | Sequence
           ;

Sequence = Sequence Sequence
         | Repetition
         | <empty>
         ;
```

Comment: Right on man; you've answered all my questions this evening. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the [source code for Plan 9 grep](http://swtch.com/usr/local/plan9/src/cmd/grep/).  The file grep.y has a yacc (LALR(1) if I recall correctly) grammar for regular expressions.  You might be able to start from the yacc grammar, and rewrite it for recursive descent parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia article on [Left Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) gives pretty good info on how to pull this off.

Comment: It's not that I need to re-factor a grammar with left recursion, but rather that I'm trying to get a feel for what the grammar should look like in general. While I've read about them a lot, I've never actually used a context-free grammar 'in the wild' so to speak.