# Context-free-grammar to represent regular expressions

Tags: regex, syntax, context-free-grammar, javacc

I'm trying to make a context-free-grammar to represent simple regular expressions. The symbols that I want is [0-9][a-z][A-Z], and operators is "|", "()" and "." for concatenation, and for sequences for now I only want "*" later I will add "+","?", etc. I tried this grammar in javacc:

```
void RE(): {}
{
    FINAL(0) ( "." FINAL(0) | "|" FINAL(0))*
}

void FINAL(int sign): { Token t; }
{
    t = <SYMBOL> {
        if ( sign == 1 )
            jjtThis.val = t.image + "*";
        else
            jjtThis.val = t.image;
    }
    | FINAL(1) "*"
    | "(" RE() ")"
}
```

The problem is in FINAL function the line `| FINAL(1) "*"` that gives me a error `Left recursion detected: "FINAL... --> FINAL...`. Putting "*" on the left of FINAL(1) resolve the problem but this is not what I want..

I already tried to read the article from wikipedia to remove left recursion but I really don't know how to do it, can someone help? :s

Comment: are you trying to make a grammar for regular expressions, or that matches the same language as some given regular expression? what you are asking is not really clear. Try providing some examples of words in the language and not in the language

Comment: I'm trying to make a grammar for regular expressions but a very simple. Some examples of words that I want accepted: `(a*|b).c, c|a, a.c*, 1|2, 1.3, etc`. Words that I don't want accepted is any that not respects the correct format for example: `a**b, a||b, a..b, a((b), etc`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Context-free grammar describing regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977884/context-free-grammar-describing-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following takes care of the left recursion

```
RE --> FACTOR ("." FINAL | "|" FINAL)*
FINAL --> PRIMARY ( "*" )*
PRIMARY --> <SYMBOL> | "(" RE ")"
```

However, that won't give . precedence over | . For that you can do the following

```
RE --> TERM ("|" TERM)*
TERM --> FINAL ("." FINAL)*
FINAL --> PRIMARY ( "*" )*
PRIMARY --> <SYMBOL> | "(" RE ")"
```

The general rule is

```
A --> A b | c | d | ...
```

can be transformed to

```
A --> B b*
B --> c | d | ...
```

where B is a new nonnterminal.